# PayPal sandbox: view billing plans and agreements on UI

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I work on PayPal integration now. So I registered REST APP inside of the sandbox, successfully performed first REST call and further operations with endpoints.

But I have a question:

Does PayPal sandbox implies some UI where I can see results of all actions with billing plans and billing agreements? 
Some web page where all API calls history is also very interesting for me as well.

I know that Stripe has it:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently I found a none-obvious place where you can see some useful information about your API calls which you performed in context of a PayPal sandbox.
Login to the Sandbox Dashboard, click on the "Transactions" link in the left menu.
There you can filter request based on apps which you created or by emails.

But I'm still wonder, is there any place where I can see entities of billing plans and billing agreements in the PayPal Sandbox UI :(